The value of homogeneous divisibility rules and of a numeration
Everyone knows about several divisibility rules. But any teacher knows how difficult students are even with the criterion of three in base ten.
For example, many teachers have encountered the classic mistake of saying that "a number is divisible by $3$ because its last digit is a multiple of $3$
. For example, $96$
is a multiple of $3$
because $3$
divides $6$
". This is indeed an interesting mistake. What could be more logical since $2$
divides $96$
because $2$
divides $6$
?
It’s the problem of learning rules in mathematics without knowing the proof of these "rules" that mathematicians call "theorem". We use them afterwards like parrots. And sometimes the parrot says nonsense. This is what we call psittacism.
There is a numeration, the primorial number system, in which all the criteria are of the same type and easily explainable to children, without creating the confusions indicated above.
I wonder if this argues for the beginning of reflection by the entire mathematical community on the relevance of gradually introducing the teaching of this numeration.

Question(Edit): In any case, we have a number system where familiarizing students with homogeneous criteria for divisibility by 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19… would be so simple since they would just have to consult termination tables to immediately answer the question: is this number divisible by 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,…? Does this argue for gradually introducing primorial number system into teaching to respond to this fundamental training in elementary arithmetic?$(1)$

It can be taught in a very simple way: I did it in the context of a course prior to the school holidays (activity presented as fun) for 11/12 year old students: it works very well and the students are surprised to learn without difficulty criteria that bother them in base ten.



Here are $n$ calculi to count. We start by forming $\color{red}{\text{bundles of two calculi}}$, then from three $\color{green}{\text{bundles of three }}\color{red}{\text{bundles}}$, we form a new bundle. We obtain$$(\color{green}3:\color{red}1:1)_{\text{Primorial}}:=\color{green}3\times 6+\color{red}1\times 2+\textbf{1}\times 1$$
We know that if a number ends by $n=(...:1:1)_{\text{Primorial}}$, then $3|n$
Then $$3|n$$

Regarding the base seven criterion, it will be enough to look at the last four "digits"$$(3:0:0:1),(0:1:0:1),(5:1:2:1),(4:2:0:1)$$$$(2:2:2:1),\color{red}{(1:3:0:1)},(6:3:2:1),(3:4:2:1)$$ If we take a famous example of Blaise Pascal, the fact that the number envisaged by Blaise Pascal was or was not divisible by seven, is then within the reach of a twelve-year-old.
Let $P=287\,542\,178$
$$P=2\times 143\,771\,089$$ $$143\,771\,089=2\times 71\,885\,544+\color{red}1$$ $$71\,885\,544=3\times 23\,951\,851+\color{red}0$$ $$23\,951\,851=5\times 4\,792\,369+\color{red}3$$ $$4\,792\,369=7\times 684\,624+\color{red}1$$
So, $$P=2\times(...:\color{red}{1:3:0:1})_{\text{Primorial}}$$ So, $$7|P$$

Edit: Who can predict the future of a number-system? The future of the primorial number system matters little to me since it is unlikely that the interest in it will evolve significantly in my lifetime. However, I do not think that the question I have (probably badly) formulated deserves to be dismissed too hastily. I asked it differently in mathematical terms probably more precise and audible in another context (here ) and it is rather well received with other questions of the same type. I hope to renew interest in this question. Best regards.

$(1)$ At the risk of appearing pedantic, I recall Gauss’s phrase: "The problem of distinguishing between prime numbers and composite numbers, and that of decomposing a number into a product of prime factors are the most important and useful of all arithmetic. […] The honor of science seems to demand that we zealously cultivate any progress in the solution of these elegant and famous questions."

It could be helpful to edit your post so that it makes clear what the actual question is. [If it is the sentence that begins: "I wonder if this argues for..." then I'm inclined to agree with the posted response of "no"]

This question clearly shows research efforts; it may suffer from a lack of clarity; but this is of little importance when considering the universal importance of a number system. This inevitably makes this question useful. This is my opinion and I give it to regret the downvotes without intervention to explain these downvotes.

This seems fun, but this particular example is $3|21$.  If a student isn't sure about $3|21$ they could rely on other facts they do know, such as $3|15$ and $3|6$, to conclude.
Let's do a more interesting example:  does $3$ divide $5230 $?
The primorials are defined similarly to the factorials but only multiplying the primes:
$$
p\# = \prod_{\stackrel{p_i \leq p}{p_i \textrm{ prime}} } p_i
$$
To calculate the primorial representation of $5230$ we need to calculate
$1\# = 1$
$2\#= 2$
$3\# = 6$
$5\# = 30$
$7\# = 210$
$11\# = 2310$
$13\# = 30030$
Then express $5230$ as $2(11\#) + 2(7\#) + 6(5\#) + 1(3\#) + 2(2\#) = (2:2:6:1:2:0)_{\textrm{primorial}}$ to conclude that $3$ does not divide $5230$.
Compare this with the "standard" approach:  $5230 \to 5 + 2 + 3 \to 10 \to 1+0 \to 1$, so $5230 \cong 1  \mod 3$.
The standard approach is conducive to mental arithmetic, while the primorial approach is not (at least to me:  perhaps there are some tricks I am not seeing).
The standard approach also has a nice story to tell:
$$
\begin{align*}
5230 
&= 5(1000) + 2(100) + 3(10) + 0(1)\\
&= 5(3\cdot 333+1) + 2(3\cdot 33+1)+3(3\cdot 3+1)+0(1)\\
&\cong 5 + 2 + 3 + 0 \mod 3
\end{align*}$$
If you are able to inspire your students (and yourself!) by playing and discovering in the primorial number system I am all for it!  There is immense value in age appropriate "research":  this definitely counts for middle school students.
I would just be careful about overselling it.  When you say

I wonder if this argues for the beginning of reflection by the entire mathematical community on the relevance of gradually introducing the teaching of this numeration.

I think the answer is simply "no".  It isn't something which everyone needs to learn.  It isn't "practical".  It is not a secret key to understanding.  I never knew about this numeration system until you posted about it just now, and I (sadly) do not feel any deeper understanding unlocking within my mind after learning about it.
It is a cool and fun side project which could inspire students.

You did not understand the first example and I find that perfectly normal, I probably was not explicit enough. Also, I will strive to be more explicit. First, there are not 27 pebbles. And your counting error is interesting because it shows you that applying the divisibility rules that you have applied presupposes having finished counting (without making a mistake). Moreover, this type of counting would be intended for young children to whom we would propose to “count” in an original way a number of pebbles that they would therefore not know a priori. We would suggest them to make packets.

(following) At the beginning simple packets of two pebbles. Then as soon as they would get three such packets, they could form a new packet. This might be simpler with plastic eggs that we would store in boxes of six eggs. The expected result would be that the children could at the end how many boxes of six eggs they obtained, how many packets of two eggs, and how many single eggs.

@StéphaneJaouen I really don't think my counting mistake is indicative of any particular misunderstanding.  I will correct my answer.  I understand how you are bundling.  What you are leaving out is the necessity of memorizing (or in some other way determining) the list of prime numbers 2, 3, 5, 7, 11,... so that you know when to bundle.  This is one of many reasons the system is inconvenient for counting and arithmetic.

First I object to "But any teacher knows how difficult students are even with the criterion of three in base ten" This is against my experience.
Then I see that to find out that PASCAL is not divisible by 7 you have to do division by 2, by 3 by 5 and finally by 7 so why not divide 287542178 directly by 7? There is no easy rule for divisibility by 7 but the rules for 2, 3, 4, 9  maybe 11 are so easy many students grasp them and use them. so your primorial numbers may get students interested in primes but nothing more. Anything a teacher is font of gets his students to follow a course with enthusiasm, like your students did , but it says nothing for its real value for math teaching.

But first you have to convert  the numbers in primordial numbers. can you go through a forest and count the trees in primordials? or the money in your purse? ow to start counting with  4 to 5 year olds? We all have 10 fingers, and there is no natural rule to divide them in groups of 2,3,, 5, 7?

I stop arguing , as I said, if a teacher ist fond of some aspect of math , ie students profit from it. but he should not propose his hobby as some topic every teacher should even consider.

The correct term here is primorial, not primordial.

For example, many teachers have encountered the classic mistake of saying that "a number is divisible by $3$ because its last digit is a multiple of $3$. For example, $96$ is a multiple of $3$ because $3$ divides $6$". This is indeed an interesting mistake. What could be more logical since $2$ divides .$96$because $2$ divides $6$? It’s the problem of learning rules in mathematics without knowing the proof of these "rules" that mathematicians call "theorem". We use them afterwards like parrots. And sometimes the parrot says nonsense. This is what we call psittacism.

I’m not "talking" about a hobby, I’m thinking about a number system. No one can predict the future of a number system. Maybe one day this one  will be used by 10 billion human beings, who knows?

Let’s imagine that we suggest a student to take an interest in
$$N=1*1+2*2+4*6+5*30+1*210+12*2310+16*30030+15*510510+1*510510*19+5*510510*19*23$$ $$N=(\color{Magenta} 5\color{black}:1:15:16:12:1:\color{orange}5:\color{blue}4:\color{green}2:\color{red}1\color{black})_{Primorial}=1\,133\,330\,279_{ten}$$
The student does not know a priori which divisibility rule to use
However, he immediately observes that$\color{red}2\nmid N$
Then that $\color{green}3\nmid N$
Then that $\color{blue}5\nmid N$
Then that $\color{orange}7\nmid N$
....................................................................................Then that $17| N$.
He thus obtains the decomposition into a product of prime factors of the semi-prime$N$ $$\boxed{N=17\times 66\,666\,487}$$

As for how to obtain the decomposition of $N$ into Primorial, here is the procedure that the student did on his small calculator: $1\,133\,330\,279 \vdash 2$ →$\color{red}1$→Ans $\vdash 3$→$\color{green}2$→Ans  $\vdash5$→$\color{blue}4$→Ans  $\vdash7$→...→Ans  $\vdash19$→$\color{Magenta} 5$.

@Steven Gubkin : hello. In my answer above, here "are some tricks [you are] not seeing". Best regards.

@Benjamin Dickman :I hope that the answer I just found will be better formulated than the question. Regards

@trula : Hello. I hope that the procedure indicated to switch from base ten to writing in primorial numeration, although it does not allow counting the trees in a forest :), will nevertheless interest you. Regards.
